# how to write python code WITHOUT selenium or bs4 to load more articles on https://techcrunch.com/

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping

I want to store the html/pdfs of 100 articles from https://techcrunch.com/ but i would have to "click load more" on the site for it to display more than 20 at a time. at present, my python code can only get the first 20, since the others are "hidden" by the load more button.

i can't use selenium or any third party web crawlers to simulate a user clicking load more... is there another way for me to get the hidden articles?

i've been trying to look at the source code but i dont know what to look for. i think i might have to use requests to simulate the data request? but not sure how to do that either.

Answer (score 0):

There is pagination API URL. When you open Web Developer Tools -> Network tab you should see it there when you click on "Load More" button:

```py
import requests

api_url = "https://techcrunch.com/wp-json/tc/v1/magazine?page={page}&_embed=true&es=true&cachePrevention=0"

for page in range(1, 10):  # <--- change the number of pages here
    data = requests.get(api_url.format(page=page)).json()
    for article in data:
        print(article["title"]["rendered"])
```

Prints:

```
...

Apple releases spatial video recording on iPhone 15 Pro
Sila inks supply deal with Panasonic for its breakthrough battery material
Apple&#8217;s new Journal app is now available with the release of iOS 17.2
We should all be paying more attention to the PDD-Alibaba rivalry
```